# php -f <filename.php> - raw PHP code output when not using <?php

Tags: php, macos

Very odd.

I ran `php -f <filename.php>` and found my terminal was simply spitting out raw PHP. I had run this file a few months previously and all fine. Took me a bit to figure out what was going on but, on a hunch, when seeing the script tag was using simply `<?` I used the full `<?php` opening tag. And all was well.

So, my question is - what has happened in the last few months that the PHP install on my Mac has changed behaviour so that I have to use the full opening tags?

Fwiw,

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.24 (cli) (built: May 19 2015 10:10:05)

OS X 
10.10.4 (14E46)
```

Comment: Maybe you changed your ini file and don't allow short open tags anymore

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: I have a similar issue with a windows, I try it on my mac and works perfectly, when I move it to a windows I need to add the full tag ```<?php```. What we discover is that this issue is somewhere configuration with the apache you install.

Comment: or you switched php installs and the new one's php.ini has them off. we can't answer this, since you haven't told us anything about how/where you got your php from.

Comment: Short open tags are discouraged for precisely this reason - it depends on your environment as to whether they work. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Yes, all I can think of is Apple upgraded PHP and there was a different php.ini.